# Ubuntu can't restart supervisor

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, supervisord

I tried:

```
sudo service supervisor restart
```

I got:

> Job for supervisor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status supervisor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Then I run:

```
systemctl status supervisor.service
```

Result:

```
supervisor.service - supervisord - Supervisor process control system
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-04-29 13:37:02 EDT; 27s ago
Docs: http://supervisord.org
Process: 23929 ExecStart=/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/supervisord --configuration /edx/ap

Apr 29 13:37:02 vu supervisord[23929]:     handlers.append(RotatingFileHandler(filename,'a',maxbytes,ba
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu supervisord[23929]:   File "/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/local/lib/python2.7
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu supervisord[23929]:     FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode)
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu supervisord[23929]:   File "/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/local/lib/python2.7
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu supervisord[23929]:     self.stream = open(filename, mode)
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu supervisord[23929]: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/edx/var/log/supervisor/
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu systemd[1]: Failed to start supervisord - Supervisor process control system.
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 29 13:37:02 vu systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 3):

The key error message is this one:

```
Permission denied: '/edx/var/log/supervisor/
```

supervisord doesn't have permission to log to the /edx/var/log/supervisor/ directory. Check that the directory exists and the user that supervisord is running as can write to it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem as below
First remove all configurations in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` and restart the supervisor with command `sudo service supervisor restart`.
After to update the supervisor process group 1. move the config file to `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/` directory, 2. run command `sudo supervisorctl reread` it will check the syntax and adds the process to supervisor group.

Other way is to uninstall and re-install the supervisor.